# TextEdit freezes on opening files via "open" menu (Monterey on MBP 16" 2019)

Tags: textedit

TextEdit freezes every time while trying to open a file from the menu `File->Open` (or CMD + O) or via menu `File->Recent files`.
But if I open a file from the Finder (by simply clicking on it) TextEdit opens it correctly without any fail.

I am having this problem on MBP 2019 driven by **Monterey Mac OS**.

Here is a few crash reports (due to their length do not fit 30k symbols they are on external links):

1. http://d2.webdemosites.top/textedit-crash-report.txt
2. http://d2.webdemosites.top/textedit-crash-report-2.txt

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**The answer below has no effect.**

I tried on an Intel Mac running Monterey 12.0.1 and easily reproduced the bug.

On M1 Mac, still on Monterey 12.0.1 there are no bugs of this type, TextEdit works perfectly.

```
You can try this :
1) you close Textedit
2) you open the Finder, click inside to get focus, then you do cmd+shift+g 
3) in the "Go to directory" Windows, you paste ~/Library/Containers
4) here you find com.apple.TextEdit and you drag it to the Desktop (with cmd key pushed).
5) you reboot your Mac and retry.
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. Sadly, it didn't help. Need to dig further. :)

Comment: That's a shame. Can you create or use a new user, connect with him and try if you have the same problem? You can also try a Safe Boot (push shift key at boot) to suppress system caches.

Comment: Dear @Jean_JD, thank you for your advice. Creating a new user made it work! I am now moving all my settings and files to the new dir. It's sorry Mac Os does not have an ability to restore built-in apps to the initial state. Thank you!

Comment: @Arsenii I've a big doubt on this solution. Have you seen my tests in my precedent response?

Comment: you mean this: "I tried on an Intel Mac running Monterey 12.0.1 and easily reproduced the bug"?

Comment: I had the same result as you. TextEdit crash on the operations you have descripte (cmd+o etc....). I don't think that create a new user resolve the bug.

Comment: Dear @Jean_JD, yes, yoг are absolutely right. It did not resolve. But, now it crashes about 1 to 10 times of tries, which is even worse, because the bag is floating. So, I have removed newly baked user and moved back to the initial home folder. TextEdit still crashing...

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this bug report. New files can be created and saved but selecting files listed in the Open Recent menu result in a spinning beachball crash. I restarted my Mac laptop running Monterey in Safe Mode. TextEdit opened files from the Open Recent menu without a problem. I have the same model MacBook Pro. I am submitting this answer because my troubleshooting identified a problem in the MacOS kernels, not the TextEdit application. All start-up login items were disabled and thus not a factor.